# Sortable and deletable select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I need to make a select element able to move and drag around as the sortable ol/uls are able to be done. e.g. [jQueryui](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fmkwpvee/) is a dummy select element that I would like this to work on. Also a button next to each word like a cross that would remove it from the list.

Having looked around it seems like sortable is only available for uls and ols though.

my dummy code:

```
<select size="10">
<option value="CA" >value 1</option>
<option value="CO" >value 2</option>
<option value="CN" >value 3</option>
<option value="CN" >value 4</option>
<option value="CN" >value 5</option>
<option value="CN" >value 6</option>
<option value="CN" >value 7</option>
<option value="CN" >value 8</option>
<option value="CN" >value 9</option>
<option value="CN" >value 10</option>
<option value="CN" >value 11</option>
<option value="CN" >value 12</option>
<option value="CN" >value 13</option>
<option value="CN" >value 14</option>
<option value="CN" >value 15</option>
<option value="CN" >value 16</option>
<option value="CN" >value 17</option>
<option value="CN" >value 18</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can't do that with a select element - you'll need to either build something or use a 3rd party component.

Comment: I have just found one that works and tried to change my version to it which didn't work so i changed the one i found to mine and it worked? Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/1534/

Comment: Ah I am new to fiddle, just saw the external resources! Jsfiddle is pretty neat huh!